# jQuery click issue with a span styled to look like a button

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-events

## Context

I've this buttons:

[image]

I detect when the user is clicking with jQuery `.click()`.

But it works only if the user clicks on the text ("*imdb*" / "*rottenTomatoes*").

If the user clicks on the blue of button, jQuery detects nothing.

[image]

You can try on http://promobluray.fr.

## Questions

- What is the problem?
- How to get this to work like a button?

## Code

**[html](/questions/tagged/html):**

```
<span class="rating">  
    <span class="rating-btn imdb active">imdb</span>
    <span class="rating-btn rt">rottenTomatoes</span>
</span>​
```

**[css](/questions/tagged/css):**

```
.rating {
    padding: 14px;
}

.rating-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 24px;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom,#2CA0CA 0,#08C 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom,#2CA0CA 0,#08C 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,#2CA0CA 0,#08C 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom,#2CA0CA 0,#08C 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom,#2CA0CA 0,#08C 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #7fd2f1,0px 6px 0 #156785;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #7fd2f1,0px 6px 0 #156785;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #7fd2f1,0px 6px 0 #156785;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.rating-btn::before {
    background-color: #072239;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    left: -2px;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 6px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}

.active {
    background: #2CA0CA;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #7fd2f1,inset 0 -1px 0 #156785;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #7fd2f1,inset 0 -1px 0 #156785;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #7fd2f1,inset 0 -1px 0 #156785;
    top: 7px;
    cursor: default;
}

.imdb {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

**[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):**

```
$('.rating-btn').click(function() { ... });
```

​

Comment: Those aren't buttons. Those are spans which have been styled to look like buttons, but their dimensions are still only the height and width (plus any padding) of the text, which is why that's the only area that registers the click event.

Comment: I'm going to try with buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to increase the padding of the button so that the `<span>` matches the dimension of the image, but i think that the best solution is to change your markup and actually use `<button>`

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to work in the latest versions of FF and IE, but not Chrome, Opera and Safari(win). I would suggest adding `display:block;` to `.rating-btn` styles to see what that does.

Alternatively, actually use buttons and style those how you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use parent to attach handler

```
$('.rating:has(.rating-btn)').click(function() { ... });
```